# SQL how to find distinct values between two tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct, distinct-values

We have an internal and an external table. The internal table is actually a copy of the external table with some fields renamed and they are roughly the same. For some reason, the data in the internal table might not match the external table because of inappropriate operation. Here is the case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Rows] 
FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car_Ex];
-- (ANS.) 76716

SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Rows] 
FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car];
-- (ANS.) 76716
```

They have the same number of rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([HORSEPOWER])) 
FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car_ex];
-- (ANS.) 459

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Horsepower])) 
FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car];
-- (ANS.) 458
```

However, the number of distinct `Horsepower` is different. I'd like to know which value of `HORSEPOWER` exists in `Auct_Car_ex` but not in `Auct_Car`. How can I find it?

Comment: Databases have columns, not fields. Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use `EXCEPT`**

```sql
SELECT acx.HORSEPOWER
FROM dbo.Auct_Car_ex acx
EXCEPT
SELECT ac.Horsepower
FROM dbo.Auct_Car ac;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,it is easy by sub-query.

```
SELECT [HORSEPOWER]
FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car_ex]
WHERE [HORSEPOWER] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Horsepower]
    FROM [dbo].[Auct_Car]
    GROUP BY [Horsepower]
)
GROUP BY [HORSEPOWER]
```

Comment: What does `id` means? We have `CarID` in `[dbo].[Auct_Car]` and `CARID` in `[dbo].[Auct_Car_Ex]`. I tried to substitute `id` with `CarID` and `CARID`. It gives an error saying `Column 'dbo.Auct_Car_Ex.CARID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: try the above that i have changed.

Comment: It returns a column name only.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for *not exists*

```
select horsepower
from Auct_Car_ex x
where not exists (
  select * from Auct_Car a
  where a.horsepower = x.horsepower
);
```